# ASP.NET Core Default debugging launch URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When using the ASP.NET Core Web API template, the default debugging start up URL is somehow set to `api/values`. Where is this default configured and how do I change it?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There was very little documentation that I could find regarding where this start up URL was declared. There is a brief mention of it in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/04/29/new-asp-net-features-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2015-rc/) on MSDN. I eventually stumbled upon it in the `launchSettings.json` file under the `Properties` node of the project as shown below:

[image]

Here are the contents of this file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName" : "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables" : {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can change the `launchURL` to your desired default route.

Comment: Adding this to the specific application launch settings I'm using worked e.g. I have profiles a different profile under profiles that I use.

Comment: More documentation about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: For any Blazor users, make sure you're editing the correct launchSettings file. There is one for the Client and Server projects.