# How to use Swagger as Welcome Page of IAppBuilder in WebAPI

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-web-api2

I try to use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) with Microsoft WebAPI 2.

For the moment, I've the following call in a method.

```
appBuilder
   .ConfigureOAuth()
   .UseWebApi(configuration)
   .UseWelcomePage();
```

If I want to use Swagger, I must use this url "https://localhost:44300/swagger" which one works very well.

I want my home page redirects to the url of my swagger, perhaps as follows but this sample doesn't works.

```
    appBuilder
       ...
       .UseWelcomePage("/swagger");
```

Any idea ?

Comment: i want similar thing, did you get this finally working, I am using it exactuly the way you use it but doesn't work ...

Comment: Change launchSettings file instead of trying to hack around with routes and default locations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002051/706363

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I got this working how I wanted by adding a route in RouteConfig.cs like so:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "swagger_root", 
            routeTemplate: "", 
            defaults: null, 
            constraints: null,
            handler: new RedirectHandler((message => message.RequestUri.ToString()), "swagger"));

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

See this code from swashbuckle to see what's going on: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Application/RedirectHandler.cs

Comment: Worked great for me when using ASP.Net WebRole.

Comment: This works only with default settings. If you want to customize your routes to swagger UI, don't copy/paste.

Comment: For .NET Core 2.1, see this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127631/1128742

Comment: this worked for me..i need to show login page before swagger any idea?

Answer (score 20):

In the `Startup.cs` file in the `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method I used this line of code to cause it to redirect on load to the swagger welcome page.

```
app.Run(async context => { 
    context.Response.Redirect("swagger/ui/index"); 
});
```

So the full method I am using is as follows

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AtlasAuthorizationServer.Startup))]
namespace AtlasAuthorizationServer
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            app.Run(async context => {
                context.Response.Redirect("swagger/ui/index");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is going to cause a green warning in visual studio. I am sure there is some way to mimic this as asynchronous with an await call in the function.

Comment: This is the leanest option. It does not require you to add `System.Web.Mvc` unlike the other answers here.

Answer (score 13):

For Asp.Net core use this:

```
app.Run(context => {
            context.Response.Redirect("swagger/ui");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
```

Comment: with the latest version, I just redirect to "swagger" and not "swagger/ui" - works a treat though.

Comment: While the redirect works, the service is not working. I get error 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' with this. Removing this, return my apps to working state. Please test your answer properly.

Answer (score 8):

In ASP.NET Core, you can simply just change the RoutePrefix when registering SwaggerUI to empty string.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
    ...
};
```

No redirect configuration required, unless you still want `/swagger` or something similar in the path.

Comment: This doesn't work w/`c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json")` or with `c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json")` once deployed ... It can't find the `.json` file. Need to add base path to the endpoint string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937002/3216970

Comment: To clear up what @mc01 is saying, this answer will not work if you're hosting the Web API in a virtual directory. If that's not your usecase (i.e. you're deploying to its own website in IIS, or to its own App Service in Azure), then this answer works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is there any way to keep the default route while also having the "base" route go to swagger without setting up a redirect?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, here is one way of doing it. Add a new MVC controller **(Not Web API)** e.g HomeController and in the Index action add the following code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Kids.Math.Api.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("~/swagger/ui/index");
    }


}
```

}

Also, make sure your route config has the follow (Note, by default it already does)

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: .NET6 solution: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298014/8225290

Answer (score 6):

If you've come here looking for the asp.net core 2 answer you can acheive the same by setting the RoutePrefix of swagger to the apps root

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My service");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;  // Set Swagger UI at apps root
            });
```

[How to redirect root to swagger in Asp.Net Core 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290683/how-to-redirect-root-to-swagger-in-asp-net-core-2-x)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and I solved it by customizing SwaggerUI url.
This is my Configuration method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var thisAssembly = typeof (Startup).Assembly;

    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

    app.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);

    httpConfig
        .EnableSwagger("api/{apiVersion}",c =>
        {
            c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\Docs.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My API");
        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi("{*assetPath}",c =>
        {
            c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "AspNetIdentity.WebApi.DocsAssets.index.html");
        });

    httpConfig.Routes.First(x => x.RouteTemplate == "{*assetPath}").Defaults["assetPath"] = "index";
}
```

This way when You go to `localhost:44300` You'll get Swagger UI as startup page.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do, just set Home Controller & Index Action as your Default, and modify your controller action as below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("~/swagger");
    }
}
```

Short and quick solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core the following pull request was created:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/486

In the meantime the following workaround can be used:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerUI(
        this IApplicationBuilder app,
        Action<SwaggerUIOptions> setupAction)
    {
        var options = new SwaggerUIOptions();
        setupAction?.Invoke(options);

        // This method reads an internal property value 
        // http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/12/c-how-to-set-or-get-value-of-a-private-or-internal-property-through-the-reflection/
        var indexSettings = options.GetPropertyValue<IndexSettings>("IndexSettings");
        // Serve swagger-ui assets with the FileServer middleware, using a custom FileProvider
        // to inject parameters into "index.html"
        var fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions
        {
            RequestPath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.RoutePrefix) ? string.Empty : $"/{options.RoutePrefix}",
            FileProvider = new SwaggerUIFileProvider(indexSettings.ToTemplateParameters()),
            EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            StaticFileOptions =
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
            }
        };
        app.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);

        return app;
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: How to use this? A working copy paste would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core, just open Properties of the application, go to Debug tab, and write Swagger in the "Launch browser" text box,

[launch browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ds9h.png)

Comment: This only works when debugging locally. The goal is to use Swagger UI as home page when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

```
public class Startup {
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
      ...
      app.UseSwaggerUI( c => {
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
         c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
      });
      app.UseMvc(); // <-- must be after 
   }
}
```

I couldn't get it to work until I placed the app.UseMvc() after the call to app.UseSwaggerUI().

Answer (score 0):

for ASP.net core you can use this in program.cs file

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.RoutePrefix = ""; c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

For .Net core 3.1 change the configuration in launchSettings.json file

> Search for launchSettings.json file
> Change the property "launchUrl" value to "swagger". refer below:

```
    "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AfterPayAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```