# How to redirect from root url to /swagger/ui/index?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a WebApi project with Swashbuckle installed onto it.

In default setup, I must open in browser `http://localhost:56131/swagger/ui/index` to view my operations description and test page. I want it to be accessible from root of the site: `http://localhost:56131/`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: were you able to resolve this @kpa6uk ?

Comment: @Sampada no, I didn't. I believe that this can be solved with some web api redirect, and swagger is just my case. I paused this task for further research.

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? Consider marking it as solution if it helped

Comment: @bsoulier of course I did but I had no chance to test it yet, sorry. I'll definitely mark your answer as such when I test it.

Comment: You can view the url - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028736/how-to-use-swagger-as-welcome-page-of-iappbuilder-in-webapi

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Influenced by [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416969/1875339), slightly modified code:

```cs
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Attribute routing
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Redirect root to Swagger UI
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Swagger UI",
            routeTemplate: "",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: null,
            handler: new RedirectHandler(SwaggerDocsConfig.DefaultRootUrlResolver, "swagger/ui/index"));

        // Configure OWIN with this WebApi HttpConfiguration
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}
```

This way it is not necessary to create new WebAPI controller as so did @bsoulier in his answer.

This solution is based on already existing class `RedirectHandler` in `Swashbuckle.Core` assembly.

Comment: Glad you pointed out the .trim('/') - I missed this first time around!

Comment: What about Asp.net Core?

Comment: @SyaifulNizamYahya try this solution for ASP.NET Core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44912390/1875339

Answer (score 10):

If you for sure use a Web API project, you can:

- enable [Http Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2),
- create the following method within an existing or new controller:

```cs
[Route(""), HttpGet]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public HttpResponseMessage RedirectToSwaggerUi()
{
    var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Found);
    httpResponseMessage.Headers.Location = new Uri("/swagger/ui/index", UriKind.Relative);
    return httpResponseMessage;
}
```

Note the use of `ApiExplorerSettings` attribute, so that it doesn't show up in the Swagger definition.

Comment: How to enable Http Attribute Routing? Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost in Package Manager Console doesnt seems to do the trick.

Comment: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

Comment: Perfect! This worked better for me as I already have some weird routes in my RouteConfig and preferred to not touch that.

Answer (score 10):

Even simpler variant of the above answer:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    [Route(""), HttpGet]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public RedirectResult RedirectToSwaggerUi()
    {
        return Redirect("/swagger/");
    }
}
```

The simpler, the better! This one works for me.

Answer (score 3):

For `.net core` in the properties launchsettings.json modify profiles and api sections to point to swagger.

```
profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "authapi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit this answer to use a preformatted text block.

Answer (score 3):

For a RESTFUL API in ASP Net Core > 2.2, ,set the default URL in Project/Properties/ Debug

[image]

And launchSettings.json will be automaticlly updated:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger/index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question, is how to automatically redirect when navigating to the root. Not how to launch to swagger. This doesn't help if a service is already running and he wants to simply navigate to the root to see the api.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .net core, go to launchSetting.json and in the line launchUrl that is by default "api/values" change it for "swagger/ui/index" or "swagger/index"

```
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger/index.html",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

Comment: how is this different from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103388/1875339

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61616923/1875339

Comment: the only one that talk about swagger ui is the mine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of `launchUrl = "swagger/index.html"` in launchSetting.Json in asp.net core 2.1/2.2

```
"ProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger/index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44333"
    }
```

Comment: Does this setting get copied to the publish directory? It doesn't appear to work for anything but development...

Answer (score 0):

if the task allows you, in _layout.chtml just add follow line to head:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/swagger'" />`

this will redirect you on swagger/index after page was loaded

Comment: As you can see, this question is for WebAPI, no html content are served there

Answer (score 0):

If you are running dotnet core, just goto properties->launchsettings.json and comment out or remove the launchUrl and set the swagger RoutePrefix to string.Empty.