# Route application root to /swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

What is the correct way to redirect request from www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/swagger?

I setup an index controller Decorated with Route("") and it works but seems like a Kludge. I assume there should be a way to specify it in the MVC routing in Startup.cs, I just can't figure it out.

```
// kludge code, how do I do this in app.UseMvc(route => route.MapRoute...
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[Route("")]
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("/swagger");
    }
}
```

Comment: was the code mentioned in the above post, working for you? As its not working in my case.

Comment: @VaultBoy14 I need some more details
1) Are using Asp.Net Core (.NET Core) or Asp.Net (.Net Framework)?
2) What Swashbuckle (Swagger) NuGet package did you install?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following redirect rule:

```
var option = new RewriteOptions();
option.AddRedirect("^$", "swagger");

app.UseRewriter(option);
```