# Swagger UI redirection from /swagger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger to generate my API documentation (ASP.NET Web API) and it's working but I still have a small issue.

My project URL is : http://localhost:55779/MyProject/api (I configured this to have the same kind of URL and the same kind of issues than our prod env).

I configure swagger to be aware of the root url :

[image]

And it's working :
[image]

(And in case you're wondering : All URL are OK with this root URL).

But I've one issue that I don't know how to deal with :

If I try to reach

> http://localhost:58779/myproject/api/swagger

Instead of :

> http://localhost:58779/myproject/api/swagger/ui/index

I get :

> http://localhost:58779/swagger/ui/index

It's the only part that doesn't take into account the root URL I configured...

Have you got any idea ?

I see in the document we can deal with custom route but in this case I don't want to change the route just disable/fix this redirection.

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.6

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I answered a similar question a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857289/unable-to-change-swagger-ui-path/45859693#45859693 Maybe it's helpful for you too.

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks it seems to solve my issue :-)