# Swagger not working with custom route in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am developing a WEB API in .NET, and I want to document this with swagger. My default route is:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But it is giving me this error when I try to access localhost:55800/swagger:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55800/swagger/ui/index'.",
  "messageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'swagger'."
}
```

I've changed the swagger's route with this command:

```
config.EnableSwaggerUi("apihelp/{*assetPath}", c => 
    ... // following lines omitted
```

But I still cannot remove "api" prefix from my routeTemplate in the MapHttpRoute method.

How can I make it recognize the route without this "api" prefix on MapHttpRoute?

Comment: Your Web API is snagging the route before it gets to Swagger. Have you thought about changing your route to begin with a segment? Such as `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to change the route template with `api` prefix, but there is a way to make it work without the `api` prefix?

Comment: pls. check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857289/unable-to-change-swagger-ui-path/45859693#45859693) helps.

Comment: @jps It is very interesting, I could make a custom route to my swagger, but it still giving me problems if I do not put the prefix `api` to routes.

Comment: so you made some progress after reading my answer? Then pls. edit your question so that we see what changed and what's the current problem.