# localhost this site can't be reached running web application in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.7, iis-express-10

I open my solution in VS2019, select the web application and press F5 to run in the debugger
The browser is set to IIS Express (Google Chrome)
localhost:51872 opens in Chrome with a message

```
This site can't be reached. 
The connection was reset 
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

In developer tools Network tab, I see an entry for localhost with status failed

[image: status is failed]

If I click the entry I can see under the Timing tab that it is Stalled and the Explanation button takes me [to this help about queueing](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation)

> Queueing. The browser queues requests when:
>   There are higher priority requests.
>   There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
>   The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache

What should I try to fix this?

I have tried two computers, both with Win 10 1903
one with build 18362-10005 and one with build 17763.615

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome
uninstalling and reinstalling internet explorer

There are several projects in the solution including a web application that does work.

The web app that does work has startup.cs, Program.cs and appsettings.json.

The one that does not work has none of these. It does have Default.aspx and Web.config. Perhaps I am missing some fundemental understanding.

Comment: May be you have a VPN running. So, disable it first. If still the issue existed, you can try Changing port number. hope this helps.

Comment: no vpn is involved. Currently I use port 51872. How do I select another one?

Comment: I notice on the working computer , when localhost starts it redirects to http://localhost:35830/swagger/index.html

Comment: To change the port number, right-click the project name, then choose properties. Under the web tab, you can change the port. It's also possible via editing .sln file. But in your case, please check this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724666/how-to-redirect-from-root-url-to-swagger-ui-index

Comment: How do I know which port to try? I tried 35830 but got the same result.

Comment: No matter, just make sure that port is empty; e.g.: 35731. But, since the issue is from swagger, check this similar thread too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857289/unable-to-change-swagger-ui-path/45859693#45859693

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. Swagger was a red-herring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197653/discussion-between-a-nadjar-and-kirsten-greed).

Comment: @A.Nadjar what is the issue with running a VPN while debugging via IIS Express?

Answer (score 1):

When I added index.html to the application I could run the project without error.