# How to set Swagger as default start page?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate

How do I set Swagger as the default start page **in ABP template** instead of `/Account/Login`?

I'm using  ASP.NET MVC 5.x + Angular 1.x.

## Update

Current code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //ASP.NET Web API Route Config
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "swagger_root",
        routeTemplate: "",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: null,
        handler: new RedirectHandler((message => message.RequestUri.ToString()), "swagger"));

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Everything is still working fine, except Module Zero's `"api/Account/Authenticate"` request that has broken, showing:

> The resource cannot be found.

Comment: For quick solution, please refer to this: [view my suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028736/how-to-use-swagger-as-welcome-page-of-iappbuilder-in-webapi/52699198#52699198)

Comment: On that same SO post right above @AbdulMueedShahid post is a much better solution for ASP.Net Core apps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127631/1179562

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416969/8601760) routing in [RouteConfig.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/aaf24a1b0b18dc11e9aba7b5101d98d1fa621b3f/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebSpaAngular/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs#L23) as commented out here:

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //ASP.NET Web API Route Config
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    // Set Swagger as default start page
    /*
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "swagger_root",
        routeTemplate: "",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: null,
        handler: new RedirectHandler((message => message.RequestUri.ToString()), "swagger"));
    */

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 51):

For a RESTFUL API in ASP Net Core >2.2, set the default URL in Project/Properties/ Debug

[image: Default URL In Resful API dot net core 2.2]

Comment: I just updated to AspNet Core 3.1, and the forward slash in the above solution is not necessary. I'm not sure if this is specific to my configuration, or in general?

Comment: This is how you use program x to do this. What if you are using program A e.g. Rider? What if you're working directly from the code?

Comment: @Urasquirrel, this answer is just a UI for the `Properties\launchsettings.json` file. You can manually edit that file. I don't know the best steps for Rider.

Answer (score 25):

I know the main question was for ASP.Net MVC, but for ASP.Net Core a good solution from this answer on a similar question (using SwaggerUI): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127631/1179562

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
    ...
};
```

Comment: This is simple and better. Just because the other provided solutions require us to make configuration settings for routes. Remember you also need to remove launchUrl from launchSettings.json if there is any provided otherwise, this will not work.

Answer (score 11):

In Asp .Net Web Api Core 3.x just do this (**RoutePrefix**):

```
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Baha'i Prayers API");
            c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger/custom.css");
            c.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
        });
```

Comment: This continues to work with Asp .Net Web Api Core 6.x

Comment: Also works with 7.x.  Note that you need the entire snipped, you can't trim it down to just RoutePrefix = String.Empty.

Answer (score 8):

I went to the Solution Explorer Panel > Properties. In there I found a file called launchsettings.json.

In this file I changed the value for the "launchUrl" parameter to "swagger/index.html" in all the sections where I found it.

It´s works for me.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to do this by filling in the Start Action of the project's properties with Specific Page > /swagger/ui/index

[image]

NOTE: I am using Swashbuckle from NuGet

Comment: It works but saves the url in user specific file. So, every developer has to do it manually.

Answer (score 5):

For .Net core 3.1, change the configuration in launchSettings.json file

> Search for launchSettings.json file Change the property "launchUrl"
> value to "swagger". refer below:

```
 "profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"AfterPayAPI": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Comment: with `net6.0`, this approach still works

Answer (score 1):

What worked well for me, both in Visual Studio, IIS Express and also in IIS. It was to create a controller with the following content:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller to display API documentation in Swagger format
    /// </summary>
    [Route("")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public class DocsController : Controller
    {
        [Route("docs"), HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ReDoc()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route(""), HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Swagger()
        {
            return Redirect("~/swagger");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Editing the launchsettings.json file worked well in Visual Studio, but insists that it doesn't work as expected when hosting the application on IIS.

In this way, I found it cleaner than creating a lot of configuration in several different locations.

Comment: thanks silvair this works great on IIS and .Net Core 6