# How to redirect root to swagger in Asp.Net Core 2.x?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm building Asp.Net Core 2.x web api integrated with Swagger. To access the swagger, I had to append /swagger to the url, eg. https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/

How can I redirect https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/ to https://mywebapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite** from Nuget

In Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

before

```
app.UseMvc();
```

add

```
var option = new RewriteOptions();
option.AddRedirect("^$", "swagger");
app.UseRewriter(option);
```

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0 API, apparently installing the Nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite is not required. This code works great, thanks to Syaiful.

Comment: I had to add this `rewriteOptions.AddRedirect("^index.html$", "api-docs")`

Answer (score 39):

In Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

You should have section where you set Swagger UI options. Add and set the RoutePrefix option to an empty string.

```
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My service");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;  // Set Swagger UI at apps root
            });
```

Comment: this is setting a route prefix to the swagger, rather than redirecting to the actual swagger root. You actually have to change in launchSettings.json -> launchUrl

Comment: @nkalfov Your approach is useful for local dev, but this approach is useful for production.

Answer (score 17):

Create a default controller like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Api
{
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/")]
        [Route("/docs")]
        [Route("/swagger")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return new RedirectResult("~/swagger");
        }
    }
}
```

Any url "/", "/docs" or "/swagger" is redirect to "/swagger".

Comment: still goes to `/api/values` after adding this?

Comment: In my case, I changed the redirect URL a bit (return new RedirectResult("~/swagger/index.html"); ) and it worked perfectly. Chrome was throwing "Too many redirects" error when URL was only "~/swagger" without index.html (you can know the reason if you analyze for a moment).

Comment: Nice and clean solution, tested with .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 10):

On Startup.cs, after:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
                  {
                      options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
```

add :

```
options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
```

this will make your root url the main api url.

Comment: In Properties folder, if I didn't set in launchSettings.json under "profiles" "launchUrl" values to "" (empty string) this above didn't work for me. Now I have this - "launchUrl": "" and it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the path /swagger/index.html and you want to redirect to it from the / (root), in aspnetcore 6 you can use the following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    ...

    endpoints.Map("/", context => Task.Run((() =>
        context.Response.Redirect("/swagger/index.html"))));

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the **launchSettings.json** file.
2. Under the **"profiles"** node depending on your setup you should
   have one or more profiles. In may case I had **"IIS Express"** and
   another with named with my project name (*e.g WebApplication1* ),
   now changing the **launchUrl** entry to **"launchUrl": "swagger"**
   solved my problem.
3. If this does not work and you have other profiles do the same and
   test.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the  launchSettings.json with 
    "launchUrl": "swagger" instead of "launchUrl": "api/values"

work for me, if that doesnt work for you remove the 
 c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;  from your  app.UseSwaggerUI configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One straitforward approach is to redirect directly via `IApplicationBuilder.Use()`:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/swagger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("swagger");
        return;
    }

    await next();
});
```