# How to change asp net core 3 API default startup controller (/ launch URL)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I have created a **default asp.net core 3 web API** with the default *wheatherforecast controller*.

Then I have added a second controller, let's call it **myController**.

Now I was wondering how I can change the default startup url so I can call a myController function inside it.

Do I have to work with **endpoints route map** ? If yes how ?

Comment: By "default startup" do you mean the URL that is inserted in the browser when the browser launches, or the controller/action that will be executed when you have an empty path?

Comment: I mean the browser one

Comment: Try this out [ASP.NET Core Default debugging launch URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002050/asp-net-core-default-debugging-launch-url)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Go to the Solution Explorer, find `launchSettings.json` file and modify the `"launchUrl"` property and set it to whatever you want.

For example in your case: `"launchUrl": "myController/myAction",`

Comment: Yes it is. My bad I haven't noticed it... but anyway thanks